# Solving Differential equation, origin Physics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, error-function

Given constants $u,v,l$ find the solution to the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}+x\left(1+\frac{v}{l}t\right)=u$$
Given that at $(0,l)$ lies on the solution.
And hence find the value of $t$ when $x=0$.

I have progressed solving this equation partially. The answer included imaginary error function and other cumbersome components. As a result I am unable to find the exact value of the parameter.

You may use approximation to find the answer to the second part, but please do mention the preciseness of the answer.

Comment: Hint: Integrating Factor. It does have parameters and the solution includes the error function. That is the solution.

Comment: I have used that.

Comment: Are you expecting a different approach and answer? That is the answer and it includes the error function. So, now I am confused as to what you are actually looking for.

Comment: I want to find the value of $t$ when $x=0$. How do you determine the parameter?

Comment: Do you have initial conditions to first resolve the constants? Then, numerical methods to the rescue.

Comment: Yeah, $t=0\implies x=l$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+1%2F%282+Sqrt%5Bv%5D%29+E%5E%28-t-%28t%5E2+v%29%2F%282+w%29-w%2F%282+v%29%29+Sqrt%5Bw%5D+%282+E%5E%28w%2F%282+v%29%29+Sqrt%5Bv%5D+Sqrt%5Bw%5D-Sqrt%5B2+%5C%5BPi%5D%5D+u+Erfi%5BSqrt%5Bw%5D%2F%28Sqrt%5B2%5D+Sqrt%5Bv%5D%29%5D%2BSqrt%5B2+%5C%5BPi%5D%5D+u+Erfi%5B%28t+v%2Bw%29%2F%28Sqrt%5B2%5D+Sqrt%5Bv%5D+Sqrt%5Bw%5D%29%5D%29%3D0%2C+t, note: I changes $l$ to $w$ so I can read it

Comment: Thanks. How do we find the inverses of imaginary error function? Can we use approximations?

Comment: I am not sure, you would have to investigate that further or ask a question. Maybe you can try it with a CAS and see if it can do it.

Comment: I don't know what CAS is. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems